# Jmeter and Influxdb: how to measure the number of bytes transferred?

Tags: networking, jmeter, influxdb, grafana

I have setup JMeter that sends data into an InfluxDb instance. I'm trying to analyze the results with grafana. I'm facing a problem: I'm not able to create a graph from the transfer speed. JMeter does not send such data to the database.

The official documentation lists several so called "real time results", and the "bytes transferred" is not present there:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html

How is that possible? This information is so basic and so useful! It should be there by default. How can I setup JMeter to send this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not possible using InfluxDB or Graphite BackendListener client.

We've create an enhancement request to send **sent bytes** (sb) and **received bytes** (rb):

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62276

We have proposed a patch which has been merged today, you should be able to test nightly build tomorrow.

It should be in next version 4.1

You can use nightly build :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html

Here is content of future 4.1 in real-time :

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&bug_status=NEEDINFO&bug_status=RESOLVED&bug_status=VERIFIED&bug_status=CLOSED&list_id=168769&product=JMeter&query_format=advanced&target_milestone=JMETER_4.1

Comment: Great, I see that it has already been fixed in trunk. But the last nightly build is from April 5. Does it mean that it fails to compile?

Comment: Use Last Successful Jenkins build for JMeter-trunk

Comment: Okay, so can you please explain what the fields are? I guess "sb" means "sent bytes" and "rb" means "received bytes"? Thank you